# Test import react-native or react-native-web

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I've React monorepo project with React-Native and React-Native-Web.

In common module, i would like use `View` and `Text` component, but i need to change my import on `mobile` (react-native) or `web` (react).

I've try this :

`const { View, Text } = window ? require('react-native-web') : require('react-native');`

But that does not work, which makes sense.

Anyone have already this use case ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

After setting up your project to use react-native-web, you simply import everything from react-native and react-native-web takes care of the rest. If you have your project configured correctly `import { View, Text } from 'react-native` is all you need, and on web react-native-web will render divs instead of View and p or whatever instead of Text. Code like it's react native.